# How would you recreate this Windows API Structure with ctypes?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I'm not entirely sure how this specific structure would be created in Python with ctypes as it has a nested `Union` block.

```
typedef struct tagINPUT {
  DWORD type;
  union {
    MOUSEINPUT    mi;
    KEYBDINPUT    ki;
    HARDWAREINPUT hi;
  };
} INPUT, *PINPUT;
```

How would you handle the nested `Union` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this union is properly never used outside `INPUT`, you could create it as a nested class:

```
class INPUT(Structure):
    class _I(Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ('mi', MOUSEINPUT),
            ('ki', KEYBDINPUT),
            ('hi', HARDWAREINPUT),
        ]

    _anonymous_ = ('i', )
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', DWORD),
        ('i', _I),
    ]
```

Even if you didn't used anonymous, it's perfectly fine to do something as `input.i.hi.uMsg`.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

class MOUSEINPUT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dx', LONG),
        ('dy', LONG),
        ('mouseData', DWORD),
        ('dwFlags', DWORD),
        ('time', DWORD),
        ('dwExtraInfo', POINTER(ULONG)),
    ]

class KEYBDINPUT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('wVk', WORD),
        ('wScan', WORD),
        ('dwFlags', DWORD),
        ('time', DWORD),
        ('dwExtraInfo', POINTER(ULONG)),
    ]

class HARDWAREINPUT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('uMsg', DWORD),
        ('wParamL', WORD),
        ('wParamH', DWORD)
    ]

class INPUT(Structure):
    class _I(Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ('mi', MOUSEINPUT),
            ('ki', KEYBDINPUT),
            ('hi', HARDWAREINPUT),
        ]

    _anonymous_ = ('i', )
    _fields_ = [
        ('type', DWORD),
        ('i', _I),
    ]
```

Comment: @sergey You can have a look here [http://codepad.org/gOXr9Uns](http://codepad.org/gOXr9Uns).